# Is concurrency on Serverless (like Google Cloud Run) pointless?

Tags: concurrency, serverless, google-cloud-run

As far as I can tell by default, on Google Cloud and presumably elsewhere, each [vCPU = 1 hyperthread](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms). (3rd paragraph in the intro) Which, from my perspective, would suggest that unless one changes this setting to 2 or 4 vCPUs, concurrency in the code running on the docker image achieves nothing. Is there some multi-threaded knowledge im missing that means that concurrency on a single hyperthread accomplishes something? scaling up the vCPU number isnt very attractive as the minimum memory setting is already forced to [2GB for 4 vCPUs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu)

This question is framed based on the Google Cloud tech stack, but is meant to umbrella all providers.

***Do Serverless solutions ever really benefit from concurrency?***

EDIT:

The accepted answer is a great first look, but I realized my above assumptions ignored context switching idle time. For example:

If we wish to write a backend which talks to a database, a lot of our compute time might be spent idling for the database request results. context switching to the next request in this case would allow us to fill CPU load more efficiently.

Therefore, depending on the use case, even on a single threaded vCPU our Serverless app can benefit from concurrency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-performances-with-multiple-cpus-a4c2fccb5192). From my experience, YES, you can handle several thread in parallel and your performance increase with the number of CPU. however, you need to have a process that support multithread.

In case of Cloud Run, each request can be processed in a thread, parallelization is easy.

Comment: very nice resource, amended my question with an obvious use case i should have seen before even asking the question, but if more people find your post through this that's great.